# TDA - Sliding window on multiple signals

Tags: python, topology

I'm trying to define a function in python that performs sliding window on multiple signals (and using the resulting SW as input for ripser).
What I want to achieve is this (examples with sines, sorry for bad drawing skills)
[picture describing my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDGNq.png)

I have 14 signals of 10000 points, so a 14 x 10000 matrix, and I want to perform a sliding window on all the signals making them correlated in some way by grouping all the points for all the signals in each window, given its dimension.

I tried first using the code made by Christoper Tralie, but this gives me an error on the dimension of X, so now I'm trying to modify it.

```
def slidingWindowMultipleSignals(I, dim, Tau, dT):
'''
Performs the sliding window on multiple signals.
Author: Christopher J. Tralie
'''
N = I.shape[0] #Number of frames
P = I.shape[1] #Number of pixels (possibly after PCA)
pix = np.arange(P)
NWindows = int(np.floor((N-dim*Tau)/dT))
X = np.zeros((NWindows, dim*P))
idx = np.arange(N)
for i in range(NWindows):
    idxx = dT*i + Tau*np.arange(dim)
    start = int(np.floor(idxx[0]))
    end = int(np.ceil(idxx[-1]))+2
    if end >= I.shape[0]:
        X = X[0:i, :]
        break
    f = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(pix, idx[start:end+1], I[idx[start:end+1], :], kind='linear')
    X[i, :] = f(pix, idxx).flatten()
return X
```

The problem is that I don't know what to modify for making it doing the thing I described with the image.
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is located in the line

```
NWindows = int(np.floor((N-dim*Tau)/dT))
```

specifically with the use of /. I'd check the dtypes of dim, Tau and dT. If all are integers, or if some are floats, / may not behave in exactly the same way.

Also, python expects the body of the function to be indented, which it isn't in your example.